# Gnuplot command with multiple "with" arguments

Tags: command-line, plot, gnuplot

### Plotting in Gnuplot:

For example if one tries to both set the datapoint type and the errorbars into one command, there's a conflict of "with" arguments, i.e.:

`plot "test.csv" using 1:2:3 with points pointtype 5 with yerrorbars`

The error message is as follows: *duplicated or contradicting arguments in plot options.*

Any suggestions how to go about this?

- Should it be split into two separate commands?
- Or is there really a way to give multiple "with" arguments in a one-liner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use two `with` arguments in a single line.

But in your case this isn't necessary, because the `yerrorbars` style also plots the points:

```
set xrange [0:1]
set samples 11
plot '+' using 1:1:($1*0.1) with yerrorbars pt 5
```

[image]

In general one can combine different plotting styles by appending more parts to a single `plot` command, like

```
plot "file.dat" using 1:2 with lines, "" using 1:2:3 with yerrorbars
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does clarify the issue (just tested it as well), +1. So in general one should opt for multiple commands for setting everything before the last command of plot, right?

Comment: In general, to combine two plottings styles you would do `plot "file.dat" using 1:2 with lines, "" using 1:2:3 with labels`

Comment: Awesome thanks! (btw freel free to add this commend to the answer, I'm sure it'd be useful for others as well, at one point or another), Cheers.

Comment: do you know how to using multiple withs when `for` is involed?
ie. `plot for[i=3:6] "file.data" using 1:i with lines, "" using 1:i:i with labels`

Comment: ah just repeating the for again works, i.e
`plot for[i=3:6] "file.data" using 1:i with lines, for[i=3:6] "" using 1:i:i with labels`